# Order date on day and month

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users with a `birth_date` and now I want to query all users who have their birthday within the next 10 days. I can't just order on `birth_date` because then I will get this:

```
01-01-1960
18-12-1975
16-12-1998
```

Instead of the desired result:

```
16-12-1998
18-12-1975
01-01-1960
```

So how can I only order on the day and month, but not the year?

Comment: Do you need sort be implemented by DB query OR Ruby code?

Comment: I prefer Ruby, but if needed DB query is also OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Ruby side you can select needed users at first(Postgresql `to_char` is used):

```
today = Date.current
dates = (today ... today + 10.days).map { |d| d.strftime('%m%d') }
dates << '0229' if dates.include?('0228') # update by SteveTurczyn
users = User.where("to_char(birth_date, 'MMDD') in (?)", dates).to_a
```

then sort them:

```
users.sort_by! do |user|
  user_yday = user.birth_date.yday
  user_yday >= today.yday ? user_yday : user_yday + 366
end
```

Comment: This won't work.  What if my birth_date was 20 years ago?  I won't be in the 'users` collection.

Comment: This User query only returns the users with a birth_date in the next 10 days. So people who are not born yet

Comment: Yep, sorry. Thought about sorting not selection.

Comment: I like this soluiton.  Might need a tweak to handle leap years? Maybe `dates << '0229' if dates.include?('0228')`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Thanks, added. We can do it more Postgres-specific by adding `order by array_position(...)` or another Postgres ordering tricks.

Comment: Yep this works like a charm, thanks @PavelMikhailyuk and @SteveTurczyn!

Answer (score 1):

This works in postgreSQL...

```
start_month = Date.today.month
start_day = Date.today.day
end_month = (Date.today + 10).month
end_day = (Date.today + 10).day

if start_month == end_month
    @users = User.where("DATE_PART('month', birth_date) = ? AND DATE_PART('day', birth_date) >= ? AND DATE_PART('day', birth_date) <= ?", start_month, start_day, end_day)
else
    @users = User.where("(DATE_PART('month', birth_date) = ? AND DATE_PART('day', birth_date) >= ?) OR (DATE_PART('month', birth_date) = ? AND DATE_PART('day', birth_date) <= ?)", start_month, start_day, end_month, end_day)
end
@users.order("DATE_PART('month', birth_date), DATE_PART('day', birth_date)")
```

This selects all records with birthdays within the next 10 days and sorts them.

If ten days in the future is still the same month (say on December 14) it selects December between 14 and 24... if it's in a future month (say on December 25) it selects December to end of month and January from beginning to the 4th.

Comment: And this does not return "desired result": `01-01-1960` will take first place.

Answer (score 1):

A ruby implementation.  Note that it may not be as performant as the DB version...

```
ids_of_next_10_days = User.all.pluck(:id, :birth_date).map do |user_info|
  next_birthday = user_info[1].change(year: Time.now.year) 
  next_birthday = next_birthday.change(year: Time.now.year + 1) if next_birthday < Date.today
  next_birthday.between?(Date.today, Date.today + 10) ? user_info[0] : nil
end.compact

User.where(id: ids_of_next_10_days)
```